# NetworkInteface GetAllNetworkInterfaces throws Catastrophic failure

Tags: c#, windows, network-programming

One of our customers has reported an issue on one of their devices and this is what we have found in their logs.

It seems they were adding and removing a VPN when it happened, but the evidence is not strong enough. Did anyone encounter similar issue?

Log:

```
System.Exception Exception System.Exception: Catastrophic failure

Catastrophic failure

at Windows.Networking.Connectivity.ConnectionProfile.get_NetworkAdapter()
at Wandera.Client.Windows.Service.Services.NetworkDataProvider.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<GetFastNetworkSignature>b__0(NetworkInterface ni)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
```

Code snippet:

````
var defaultProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

if (defaultProfile == null)
{
    Logger.Debug("FastNetworkSignature reports offline because GetInternetConnectionProfile returns null.");
    return "";
}

var level = defaultProfile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel();

if (level != NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess)
{
    Logger.Debug($"FastNetworkSignature reports UWP NetworkConnectivityLevel as {level}.");
}

var networkInterface = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(ni =>
    Guid.Parse(ni.Id) == defaultProfile.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId);```
````

Comment: Try an ipconfig command from cmd on your machine to check the status of your network interfaces and post the result.

Comment: Thanks I reported this to our client-facing team and they will run ipconfig /all and send me the output.